# Random access write to SAF file on Android

Tags: java, android, stream, storage-access-framework

I am trying to implement "random access" write to a stream retrieved from Android Storage Access Framework.

In my scenario, I pick a file using `OPEN_DOCUMENT` intent which gives me a document URI. Then I can use the `ContentResolver` to `openOutputStream`. From that point though, I don't see a way to "seek" within the stream to write on a given position within the file.

Is there a way to achieve this (at least for local storage/SD card-based files)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> at least for local storage/SD card-based files

You do not know that is what you are getting. The user can choose any document provider the user wants (e.g., Google Drive).

> I don't see a way to "seek" within the stream to write on a given position within the file

Partly, that's because Java streams suck. But, mostly, it's for flexibility for the document provider. Suppose the user chooses a provider that stores its content locally, but encrypted by a stream cipher. You can't then just jump to some arbitrary spot — the data has to be decrypted along the way.

AFAIK, your only option is to copy the content to some file that you control, after which you have random access to that file.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response. Just to further investigate - when SAF grants me access to a URI and that specific URI represents a local file, that does not grant me the ability to work with that file path directly and I still have to go through the `ContentResolver`, correct? (because otherwise I could use `RandomAccessFile` with the file path)

Comment: @MartinZikmund: "that does not grant me the ability to work with that file path directly" -- you do not know what the file path is. For example, let's go back to the "provider that stores its content locally, but encrypted by a stream cipher" from my answer. This provider stores the content as a file on the filesystem in that app's `getFilesDir()`. The `Uri` does not have to identify what the path is to that file. And even if you use some script-kiddie algorithm to reverse-engineer the path, you have no filesystem rights to it, and the content is encrypted.

Comment: @MartinZikmund: I will readily agree that the SAF is not a great API, and I have run into this specific sort of problem before (for media playback). Unfortunately, "it is what it is".